# Trouble with car audio system

Tags: toyota, audio, prius, bluetooth

I recently got a used 2016 Toyota Prius C. This is the first car I've driven that has built-in bluetooth audio, and I've gotten that working just fine, but everything I play just shows the generic "Other/misc" image instead of the cover art. I tried checking and unchecking the "show cover art" option in the settings, but that didn't help. I know for a fact that the cover art exists; I went out of my way to add ID3 cover art to the ones that lack it, even. How can I get this cover art to be recognised by the car stereo?

If it's not possible, no big deal (it's far from an important issue), but I'd like to know what makes it impossible, too.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Have you made sure that data is being sent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the BT device providing the media (presumably your phone) and the device receiving the media need to support AVRCP v1.6 in order to transmit/display album art images over Bluetooth. So it's possible that either the  car, phone (or potentially both) don't support it.

**Edit following update from the OP:**

> It's an LG G5, using Rocket Audio Player. OS is just whatever the latest version of android is available for that phone.

Latest Android version for the G5 is Oreo so assuming you are running to see if you can enable AVRCP 1.6 you'll first need to [enable developer options](https://www.theandroidsoul.com/enable-developer-options-android-o-8-0/) (if you haven't already) and then you're for an option in the "Developer options" menu called "Bluetooth AVRCP version", if your phone supports it you'll need to set that to "AVRCP 1.6" - *might* need to reboot and re-pair the bluetooth for that change to take effect.

This will at least eliminate one of the potential causes - if it's still not displaying after that then it's likely that the car doesn't support it, I've seen *some* anecdotal claims of it working over Bluetooth in Priuses but nothing definitive one way or the other.

Comment: I would assume the car does from the fact that it has the option in the first place to display album art. Would the phone side of it be hardware-dependent (i.e. can't change it without getting a new phone) or software-dependent (i.e. a different audio player or an update might let it work)?

Comment: Not necessarily - many can display album art when playing from other sources (such as SD cards, USB etc). Phone side is typically software, and it's usually governed at an OS level - so depending on available updates it may necessitate a hardware replacement.  If you can add in details about what Phone/OS/Media player you're using that would help.

Comment: It's an LG G5, using Rocket Audio Player. OS is just whatever the latest version of android is available for that phone.

Comment: Well! I've done that, so now we'll have to see if it works next time I'm in the car. Thanks for that!

Comment: Forgot to come back to this--I tried it, and it didn't help, so I'm assuming the car just doesn't support it. Thanks!

Comment: @Hearth sorry to hear it didn't work out!

Comment: Ah, it's not like it really matters anyway.